# AWS Ubuntu using public/private key ssh, trying to start a deamon asks for password

Tags: ssh, authentication

I set up a new Ubuntu machine on AWS using public/private key as authentication without a password protecting the key (it was generated by the AWS console). I copied the key to my local machine and I am able to login to the remote machine successfully using ssh.

Problem: I am trying to run docker on the remote machine using

`systemctl start docker`

and I get asked for a password:

> Authentication is required to start 'docker.service'.
> Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)

I did not setup any password, how can I tell the shell to use my key instead?

Comment: It is probably the key ring or the login manager. Different passwords. did it come with the container? Regarding the message, I've never ran it inside a docker container. Not sure how it is set up. Id check the info on dockerhub, or wherever you got it.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you need to perform Docker commands with `sudo`. Try this:

```
sudo service docker start
```

If you would like the default user account to perform Docker commands *without* `sudo`, then you'll need to add `ubuntu` to the `docker` group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
```

You can then test the permissions with something like:

```
docker info
```

If you get a permissions issue, you may need to disconnect from the EC2 instance, then reconnect.

Comment: Thank you @matigo for a complete answer.